# What's an algorithm to get a number closest to a constant that can evenly (within a margin) divide into two other constants?

Tags: algorithm, math, language-agnostic

So let't say I have numbers A=1483 and B = 635. My X=100.0

Let's say my allowed MARGIN is 10.0

What's the best way to get the closest number to X (can be floating point) that can divide into A and B with a remainder that is less that MARGIN?

For an answer K. A % K <= MARGIN, B % K <= MARGIN, with K being as close to X as possible, for example |K - X| < 100

Comment: what have you tried so far? What's the brute force method?

Comment: @ShawnMehan So far I've tried increasing by an interval 0.001 and keep checking to see the modulo over X of both is under the margin

Comment: what does "evenly divide into...." mean? "A*B" is divisible by both A and B - is that good enough?

Comment: good. What about finding the gcd(A, B). What would those gcds tell you about your solutions space?

Comment: @sds The constraint is to be as close as possible to X and the remainder under MARGIN. A * B is not close to X.

Comment: @ShawnMehan The only thing I can think of if I had the GCD would be the same brute force method, but going down

Comment: can you spec out the requirements on the answer? no words, just inequalities.

Comment: Similarly, if you factorize A and B, you will be able to see what is going both into A and B.

Comment: @sds For an answer K.   A % K <= MARGIN, B % K <= MARGIN, with K being as close to X as possible, for example |K - X| < 100

Comment: @ShawnMehan Would that method take into account floating points? My answer (K) does not need to be an integer

Comment: no, please put it into your question. people should not have to keep guessing what you mean until they read the 9th(!) comment,

Comment: I think that thinking about the factors and even the gcd gets you to a better starting position in your hunt for X

Comment: @ShawnMehan That's a good point. Correct me if I'm completely wrong, but would it be a good idea to make a cost function for the answer K, then find its gradient and use gradient descent to get it to its lowest point?

Comment: Sounds like a good experiment to conduct :)

Comment: I'll try that and post an answer if I'm successful. I just have to get past not knowing exactly how a modulo is derived

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try and write the problem with mathematical notations.

What you have is Euclidean divisions:

```
A = Q1*X + R1
B = Q2*X + R2
```

You want to find the minimal |x|  such that

```
A = Q1'*(X+x) + R1' , |R1'| <= M
B = Q2'*(X+x) + R2' , |R2'| <= M
```

To help you finding such x, you have relations like:

```
A = Q1*(X+x) + R1-Q1*x
B = Q2*(X+x) + R2-Q2*x
```

From here, you should first concentrate on how to solve the example you gave, then try and generalize.

```
1483 = 14*100 + 83 = 15*100 - 17
 635 =  6*100 + 35 =  7*100 - 65
```

Should you can take x > 0 in order to reduce R2 (35) down to 10, or x < 0 to increase R1 (-17) up to -10?

In the first case, x should be in interval [25/6 , 45/6] to bring |R2'| <= M, but at the same time it must be in interval [73/14 , 93/14] to bring |R1'| <= M.

Do these intervals overlap?

- if yes you have a solution.
- if no, then you have to try further (decrement quotients Q1' and/or Q2')

Just check with any decent interpreter (Squeak/Pharo Smalltalk here)

```
 {25/6 . 45/6. 73/14 . 93/14} sorted
 = {(25/6) . (73/14) . (93/14) . (15/2)}
```

So they overlap, starting at x=73/14.
But maybe you would get a closer x in the other direction?

I have not given an algorithm, just a clue, up to you to continue. But you see that increment does not have to be random (like 0.001).

Answer (score 0):

For now the best way I have found is a brute force method by finding the GCD of A and B and decrease by a small interval (0.001) and find the smallest c(K) where K >= X and c(x) = A % x + B % x

If I had found a way to differentiate c(x) correctly, I would've liked to find its gradient and use gradient descent to find the most optimal value without brute force.